# How to manage multiple independent deployments in Terraform

Tags: jenkins, terraform, vmware

our developers and QAs need to automatically deploy infrastructure of multiple VMs into vmware cluster for testing and developing purposes. Each dev or QA can have one or more infrastructures managed exclusively by him. We need to trigger the deployment either ad-hoc or automatically (typically in nightly fashion).

The use cases:

- Developer A wants to deploy new infrastructure with the current build of the app.
- Developer B wants to redeploy already existing infrastructure with a new build
- Developer C wants to destroy his infrastructure he doesn't need anymore
- Developer A wants to deploy another infrastructure with another build in the parallel with the first one.

We would like to use Terraform for this but there is a problem with management of multiple state files. Also we would like to see the current deployments and manage them (e.g. run redeploy or destroy operation). We had an idea to create a Jenkins job and keep the status files in different directories in the workspace, but it's not user friendly and robust. We prefer to use a tool which can "wrap" the Terraform and do this stuff for us. But unfortunatelly we are not able to find anything suitable. We have checked https://scalr.com/, http://www.glitterlabs.com/terraform_ui/index.html or https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/. None of them were suitable.

Can you recommend some tool for this? Or a good approach how to do it using jenkins (gitlab)?

Comment: If you're using Gitlab is there a reason you need to use Jenkins here rather than Gitlab CI?

Comment: Jenkins Pipeline has much better support for Terraform and other software in general, but probably there are multiple other undescribed reasons for the decision.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you can't easily trigger gitlab CI by button and provide name of the state, you want to modify. Jenkins has better gui for providing user parameters

Comment: Terraform workspaces are the official answer to this problem - spinning up a new workspace per dev or per branch could be the answer, although that might require changing some of your terraform code to template in workspace names.

Comment: I ask because Gitlab CI has a pattern around review environments that we use extensively for exactly this kind of thing.